# Craft Commerce: Multiple redirect submit buttons from cart form (checkout/update cart) without ajax

Tags: craft3, templating, php, plugin-craftcommerce3

I'm building a basic cart page in Craft 3.7.37 with Commerce 3.4.12. The `/store/cart` page has a `<form>` with the line items in the cart next to an `<input />` to change quantity and one to remove the line item. I also have an "Update Cart" button that updates quantities from the form (redirecting back to `/store/cart`) and a "Checkout" button that currently just submits the form. I've added a [`redirectInput`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#redirectinput) function to the form to redirect back to `/store/cart` on submit, which works for the "Update Cart" and "Remove" buttons.

How do I make the "Checkout" button redirect to `/store/checkout/contact` and update cart quantities when the user clicks it?

I know this is possible in PHP server side but I'm not great at PHP. I'm hoping there's a a way to use Craft's built-in functions. I want to avoid using jQuery ajax and Javascript form processing if possible (as in this [question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15627/craft-commerce-add-to-cart-and-then-redirect-to-product-page)). I also want to ensure [urls are hashed](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28794/craft-3-registration-form-success-redirect).

Here's the relevant template code:

```
<form method="POST" data-cart>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart" />
{{ redirectInput('/store/cart') }}
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="gatewayId" value="{{ gatewayId }}" />
{% set item = item | default(false) %}
{% set maxQty = maxQty | default('') %}
{% set summary = summary | default(false) %}
{% if item %}
{% set sum = item.price * item.qty %}
{% if summary %}
<p class="cart-items__item__summary">
    {{ item.qty }} &times; {{ item.price | currency }} = {{ sum | currency }}
</p>
{% else %}
<div class="cart-items__item__fields">
    <label class="cart-items__item__qty">
        {{ item.price | currency }}
        &times;
        <input max="{{ maxQty }}" min="0" name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][qty]" placeholder="qty" step="1" type="number" value="{{ item.qty }}" />
        =
        {{ sum | currency }}
    </label>
    <label class="cart-items__item__remove">
        <input name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][remove]" type="submit" value="{{ item.qty }}" />
        Remove
    </label>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
<div class="actions">
    <a href="/store" class="button actions__action">&larr; Back to Store</a>
    <button type="submit" class="button actions__action">Update Cart</button>
    <button type="submit" class="button actions__action">Checkout &rarr;</button>
</div>
```

and a screenshot of the front-end to help clarify:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use the [browser-native `<button type="submit">` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)!

Check this out:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('commerce/carts/update-cart') }}

  {# ...your existing form controls... #}

  <button
    type="submit"
    name="redirect"
    value="{{ 'update/path/target' | hash  }}">Update Quantities</button>

  <button
    type="submit"
    name="redirect"
    value="{{ 'checkout/path/target' | hash  }}">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

The only peculiar thing to note here is the direct use of Craft's [`hash` filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#hash)—ultimately the same functionality that `redirectInput()` helper provides, as a means to prevent tampering with the values and exposing your app to remote code execution vulnerabilities!

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. For anyone else wondering the `hash` filter is necessary. If you don't do it you'll get `HTTP 400 – Bad Request`.